# Alternating/looping section dividers

Tags: loops

I would like to create a section dividers that alternate/loop around several possibilities.

Code I have now:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{halloweenmath}
\def\SectionDivider{$$\mathwitch \mathwitch \mathwitch$$}

\begin{document}

1
\SectionDivider
2
\SectionDivider
3
\SectionDivider
4
\SectionDivider
5
\SectionDivider
6
\SectionDivider
7

\end{document}
```

Output PDF I have now:

[image]

Output PDF I want:

[image]

The above desired PDF was accomplished with the following code, but I want \SectionDivider to do this automatically for me, looping through (i) witches; (ii) pumpkins; and (iii) ghosts.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{halloweenmath}
\def\SectionDivider{$$\mathwitch \mathwitch \mathwitch$$}

\begin{document}

1
\SectionDivider
2
$$\pumpkin \pumpkin \pumpkin$$
3
$$\mathrightghost \mathrightghost \mathrightghost$$
4
\SectionDivider
5
$$\pumpkin \pumpkin \pumpkin$$
6
$$\mathrightghost \mathrightghost \mathrightghost$$ 
7

\end{document}
```

Comment: See [Why is `\[` ... `\]` preferable to `$$` ... `$$`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/5764)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcounter{SecDiv}\setcounter{SecDiv}{-1}
\usepackage{halloweenmath}
\newcommand{\SectionDivider}{\stepcounter{SecDiv}
\ifnum\theSecDiv=3
\setcounter{SecDiv}{0}
\fi
\typeout{\theSecDiv}
\ifcase\theSecDiv
$$\mathwitch \mathwitch \mathwitch$$
\or
$$\pumpkin \pumpkin \pumpkin$$
\or
$$\mathrightghost \mathrightghost \mathrightghost$$
\fi
}

\begin{document}

1
\SectionDivider
2
\SectionDivider
3
\SectionDivider
4
\SectionDivider
5
\SectionDivider
6
\SectionDivider
7

\end{document}
```

[image]